# Process.Start() differences between Windows and Linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core

I'm experiencing some differences in `Process.Start()` in a .NET Core 2.2 project.  You can find the full source in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jchristn/5a2a301baedeed787a2e57cd528e46d6

I have a method for starting processes:

```
private static void ExecuteShell(
    string filename, 
    string args, 
    bool useShellExecute,
    bool redirectStdOut,
    bool redirectStdErr,
    out int returnCode, 
    out string consoleOutput)
{
    returnCode = 0;
    consoleOutput = null;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filename));

    // fileName, i.e. "cmd.exe"
    // args, i.e.     "/c dir /w"

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = useShellExecute;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = redirectStdOut;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = redirectStdErr;
    process.Start();
    if (process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput) consoleOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    returnCode = process.ExitCode;
}
```

And the caller looks like this:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Example: cmd.exe /c dir /w");
        Console.Write("Command: ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput)) break;

        string[] parts = userInput.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);

        string filename = parts[0];
        string arg = null;
        if (parts.Length > 1) arg = parts[1];

        bool useShellExecute = InputBoolean("  Use shell execute  : ", false);
        bool redirectStdOut =  InputBoolean("  Redirect stdout    : ", false);
        bool redirectStdErr =  InputBoolean("  Redirect stderr    : ", false);

        int returnCode;
        string consoleOutput;

        ExecuteShell(
            filename,
            arg,
            useShellExecute,
            redirectStdOut,
            redirectStdErr,
            out returnCode, out consoleOutput);

        Console.WriteLine("Return code    : " + returnCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Console output : " + consoleOutput);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + Environment.NewLine + SerializeJson(e, true));
    }
}
```

The simplest way to reproduce the larger issue I'm having is this.  Assume there is a file on the file system and I want to `type testfile > testfile2`, i.e. to pipe to another file.

On Windows, if I use `cmd.exe /c type testfile > testfile2` it works great (with the three Boolean values set to `false`).

i.e.

```
C:\Code\ExecuteShell\ExecuteShell\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2>dotnet ExecuteShell.dll

Example: cmd.exe /c dir /w
Command: cmd.exe /c type testfile > testfile2
  Use shell execute  :  [y/N]?
  Redirect stdout    :  [y/N]?
  Redirect stderr    :  [y/N]?
Return code    : 0
Console output :

Example: cmd.exe /c dir /w
Command:
C:\Code\ExecuteShell\ExecuteShell\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 72E2-466A

 Directory of C:\Code\ExecuteShell\ExecuteShell\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2

... portions removed ...
04/09/2020  05:41 PM                15 testfile
04/09/2020  05:41 PM                15 testfile2
```

When I try this on Ubuntu 14.04 it fails.

```
~/code/ExecuteShell/ExecuteShell/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish$ dotnet ExecuteShell.dll

Example: cmd.exe /c dir /w
Command: cat testfile > testfile2
  Use shell execute  :  [y/N]?
  Redirect stdout    :  [y/N]?
  Redirect stderr    :  [y/N]?
Hello, world!

cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: testfile2: No such file or directory
Return code    : 1
Console output :
```

If I try it with `useShellExecute` set to `true`, I get this strange `xdg-open` issue:

```
~/code/ExecuteShell/ExecuteShell/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish$ dotnet ExecuteShell.dll

Example: cmd.exe /c dir /w
Command: cat testfile > testfile2
  Use shell execute  :  [y/N]? y
  Redirect stdout    :  [y/N]?
  Redirect stderr    :  [y/N]?
xdg-open: unexpected argument 'testfile'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.
Return code    : 1
Console output :
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you're confusing the use of the word “shell” in its Unix context (a command line interpreter) with its Windows and [C# use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8):

> The word "shell" in this context (UseShellExecute) refers to a graphical shell (similar to the Windows shell) rather than command shells (for example, bash or sh) and lets users launch graphical applications or open documents.

So `useShellExecute` actually means that you can give the program a document of some type and expect it to be opened by a suitable program.  That's what `xdg-open` does, so that's probably why C# invokes it.

In your case, the command you want to run is `sh -c 'cat testfile > testfile2'`.  That's the equivalent of your `cmd` invocation.  However, your code won't work if you do that now because you split on whitespace.  So you'll end up with the arguments `sh`, `-c`, `'cat`, `testfile`, `>`, and `testfile2'`.  Unlike `cmd`, which is responsible for its own argument processing, `sh` does not concatenate its commands with whitespace, and this won't work.

If you were passing this as an array of arguments, you'd want your arguments to be `sh`, `-c`, and `cat testfile > testfile2`; that is, the entire string you want to pass to the shell should be one complete argument.

Comment: Thanks @bk2004.  If I understand you correctly, I assume that 1) useShellExecute should be ```false```, 2) ```process.StartInfo.FileName``` should resolve to ```sh```, and 3) ```process.StartInfo.Arguments``` should resolve to ```-c 'cat testfile > testfile2'```.  Are these correct?

Comment: Hi @bk2004, this worked with the code as is.  Note I had to use ```"``` instead of ```'``` (double quote).  My String.Split splits into two pieces at the first whitespace, so the ```process.StartInfo.FileName``` was resolving correctly to ```sh``` and the balance went into ```process.StartInfo.Arguments```.  Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

`Process` is a fairly opaque and convoluted abstraction and unfortunately it has lots of undocumented pitfalls, mostly because it attempts to emulate Windows-like behaviour on Unix. The only way to figure out exactly what it's doing is to read the latest and greatest .NET source code.

`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` behaves weird on Unix-like systems:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cc585f6d611b4d0cef2b19c4a1ca1e5ec435e80c/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Unix.cs#L408-L446

It does the following in order:

1. Attempts to resolve absolute executable path. If the path is "rooted" (starts with /), it uses it as is. If the path is a URI, and that URI describes a local path on the system, it uses the local path as the path. If the filename is relative, it resolves it into an absolute path by first searching the working directory, and then by searching the current `PATH`. Finally, it checks the file at the path has the x (Execute) bit set, and if it doesn't, throws it away.
2. If the absolute path was resolved, and the file appears to be executable, it attempts to execute it directly.
3. If the file couldn't be executed directly, attempt to find the default program that can be used to open the file. This is operating system dependent. On Linux, it searches for any of "xdg-open", "gnome-open", "kfmclient" in the path. On FreeBSD, it tries to use "/usr/local/bin/open". On OSX, it tries to use "/usr/bin/open".
4. Finally it runs the default program which takes the original filename as the first argument and the rest of the arguments after that.

So, this is why you get that `xdg-open` error. It's attempting to open the file with a Window Manager to simulate how Windows operates. For this reason `UseShellExecute = false` is almost always preferable on Unix.

As for the arguments issue, it causes problems because .NET is splitting the string into an `argv` array using its own little state machine tokenizer:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cc585f6d611b4d0cef2b19c4a1ca1e5ec435e80c/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Unix.cs#L853-L945

This notably ignores single quotes (`'`), only recognizing double quotes (`"`). Again, it's an annoying abstraction over what's actually passed to the process, the `argv` array.

It's much better to ignore `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` entirely and instead add individual arguments with `ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList.Add()`, which will cause them to be translated directly into the process `argv` array.