Calling `pod install` from a System.Diagnostics.Process
When we build our Unity project for iOS, it generates an Xcode project which uses Cocoapods. I'm trying to make a build post-process script (C#, running in the Unity Editor) that edits the Podfile and then runs pod install in the build directory.
I've tried several different approaches to run pod install which all fail in one of two ways:
private static void ExecuteProcess(string directory, string argument) {
    try {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo() {
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = directory,
            Arguments = " -c \"" + argument + " \""
        };

        System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process {
            StartInfo = startInfo
        };
        myProcess.Start();
        while (!myProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
        var line = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(line);
        }

    } catch (System.Exception e) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e);
    }
}

private static void TryInstallPods() {
    const string BUILDS_PATH = "./Builds";
    string shellScriptPath = Path.Join(BUILDS_PATH, "podinstall.sh");

    // Outputs nothing
    File.WriteAllText(shellScriptPath, "pod install --verbose");
    ExecuteProcess(BUILDS_PATH, "sh podinstall.sh");

    // Outputs "CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update"
    File.WriteAllText(shellScriptPath, "/usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose");
    ExecuteProcess(BUILDS_PATH, "sh podinstall.sh");

    // Outputs nothing
    ExecuteProcess(BUILDS_PATH, "pod install --verbose");
    
    // Outputs "CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update"
    ExecuteProcess(BUILDS_PATH, "/usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose");

    // For reference, this works as expected for the build directory:
    ExecuteProcess(BUILDS_PATH, "ls");
    // This also works as expected:
    ExecuteProcess(BUILDS_PATH, "/usr/local/bin/pod --help");
    // This produces no output:
    ExecuteProcess(BUILDS_PATH, "pod --help");
}

Note that this shell script is generated by the code:
podinstall.sh
/usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose



From my C# code, pod install --verbose produces no output, whether it's called directly or from inside a shell script.
From my C# code, "/usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose" produces the output "CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update", whether it's called directly or from inside a shell script. Nothing else happens and the pod configuration isn't updated.

I get the same results if I try the approach described here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/adjusting-pods-pods-xcproject-after-pod-install.1406500/
However, any variation works if I open a terminal window in the build folder and type the command there:
% pod install --verbose

% /usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose

% sh podinstall.sh

The process is not deadlocking; removing the direction for standard input and output does not make the pod install command work (verified by checking the Podfile.lock and seeing that it hasn't changed).
Why do these commands work if I type them into the terminal window, but not when I try to run them from a process in C#/Unity?
Note: I have reformatted the code for this question; this question might contain typos that are not present in the original code.

This question is similar to: Programmatically running `npm run build` does not generate `index.html` for Angular 8 app. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why do you have RedirectStandardInput = true? You aren't doing anything with StandardInput.

@Serg My question is specifically about why the pod install command is not behaving the way I want. The process isn't deadlocking; commenting out some or all of the redirection does not make the pod install command succeed.

@user246821 I started from an example script; commenting out that line makes no difference in the output.

Try the code in this post, but also include WorkingDirectory property. Ensure you use fully-qualified FileName.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132464/process-start-differences-between-windows-and-linux

@user246821 Thank you! Redirecting the error output led me to the error message I needed (I hadn't realized that errors only go to StandardError and not StandardOutput >_< ); pod install wants the shell to be set to UTF-8. I've posted an answer.

user246821 helped point me in the right direction. After redirecting the error output to the console, I found an error message that pod install requires the shell to be set to UTF-8. Adding an environment variable to the process fixes this:
private static void TryInstallPods() {
    RunCmd("/bin/bash", BUILDS_PATH, "/usr/local/bin/pod install");
}

private static void RunCmd(string exePath, string directory, string arguments = null) {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, arguments);
    startInfo.Arguments = " -c \"" + arguments + " \"";
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = directory;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    startInfo.Environment["LANG"] = "en_US.UTF-8"; //REQUIRED FOR POD INSTALL

    using (Process p = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true }) {
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
            if (!System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
            if (!System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        p.Start();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}


If you found the code in my referenced post helpful, consider giving it an upvote.

@user246821 Sure thing, sorry I forgot to do that before!
